# Recompose my layout after getting Retrofit response

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get my layout to update based on the data coming from my retrofit response. I get the data from an API across the internet and I want to display the data in a Text composable to display the data to the user. I have tried using two different mutable states with no luck on recomposing and the layout does not update the UI.

**NOTE:**
I know that this is the perfect opportunity to use dagger and hilt, but for his project, I would rather stick to the usual Jetpack Compose (and because dagger-hilt just goes right over my head when I try to learn it)

Here is my code for my composable:

```
@Composable
fun PlantsMenu(){
    val plantsFinishedLoading = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val plantsData = remember { mutableListOf<SpeciesListPlant>() }

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL_PERENUAL)
            .build()
            .create(SpeciesListInterface::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getSpeciesList()

        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<SpeciesListResponse?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<SpeciesListResponse?>,
                response: Response<SpeciesListResponse?>
            ) {
                val responseBody = response.body()!!

                // Add the items to the plants array to force recomposition
                for (item in responseBody.data) {
                    plantsData.add(item)
                    Log.e("Response", item.commonName)
                }

                plantsFinishedLoading.value = true
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SpeciesListResponse?>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
    }
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
    ){
        Text("Plants")
        // I want to display the contents of my result in this list
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            items(items = plantsData, itemContent = {
                Text(it.commonName)
            })
        }
        Text("End")
    }
}
```

This composable is used in a bottom navigation bar and only updates after clicking off and on it about 3-4 times, however I want this to update directly after I get the retrofit response as shown in the code above. How can I do this after I get my API response?

Comment: i think val plantsData = remember { mutableListOf<SpeciesListPlant>() } should be state, and you have to emit whole list responseBody.data